# Create Secondary Google Calendar

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to programmatically create a new Google Calendar in one google account based on a unique input.

Also, I will need to read and add events to that specific calendar in the future.

The names of the calendars will be unique so I was wondering how I would go about creating a new calendar, and how I can read/write to/from a calendar based on the unique title name.

Even a small bit of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a link to .net documentation. Those were for Java, Ruby, PHP, and phyton.

Comment: If it's not there, it doesn't seem there is any. The closest I found was [this](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Calendar_1_1v3_1_1CalendarService.html) but that just seems to be built from reflection, so probably isn't any more helpful.